# How to access url

Tags: url, flex4

I'm using Flex 4, ActionScript 3.

In my application, I have a Help menu bar item, with Documentation as a sub-item.

My documentation is an html file, and it is deployed as part of the application, and hence will have a relative path to the application.

I want to display the content of this html file when you choose Help -> Documentation.

I tried Googling "flex access url" but the links are about accessing variables in url fragments.

How can I just access the url itself to display the contents of the file?

Thanks!
Bon :-D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Adobe AIR, you would use the [mx.controls.HTML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html) component, and do something like:

```
<mx:HTML location="app:/docs/help.html" />
```

where **help.html** is your page, and it is located in the folder **docs** in your application directory.